# How to read data from a file stored in web server by java program

Tags: java

I have stored a text file in google docs and that is a shared public file. I am trying to read the content of that file by the url. but it is not showing the contents. I am attaching my code here. Please suggest me where should I change my code to read the content of the file.the address I have given in URL is showing content when I am writing it in the address bar of any web browser. I actually do not know where to correct the code. I have added the output at the end of the code

```
package FileContent;

import java.awt.*; 
import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 

public class FileContent extends Frame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        TextArea FileText = new TextArea("  Content of the File \'temp1.txt\' :", 11, 24, TextArea.SCROLLBARS_NONE);

        try {
            // here is the url
            URL url = new URL("https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9MOgXFCss2iSWpicmVKSW9OOWM/edit");

            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Bad URL");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Error : " + e.getMessage());
        }

        FileText.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        FileText.append(String.valueOf('\n'));

        Frame f = new Frame("File Content");
        f.setSize(200, 200);
        f.add(FileText);
        f.setVisible(true);

        try {
            String s;
            boolean eof = false;
            s = br.readLine();

            while (!eof) {
                FileText.append(s + String.valueOf('\n'));
                try {
                    s = br.readLine();
                    if (s == null) {
                        eof = true;
                        br.close();
                    }
                } catch (EOFException eo) {
                    eof = true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("IO Error : " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Error : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }    
}
```

The output looks like : Time    Temperature
,"docs-ndt":"Untitled Texmex","docs-eit":false,"docs-spfe":true,"docs-mriim":1800000,"docs-ecc":false,"docs-collaborator-selection-model":false,"docs-csmbocj":false,"ecbsl":true,"ecid":true,"eod":true,"docs-eilb":false,"docs-pedd":true,"docs-evr":false,"docs-enmr":false,"docs-esrd":false,"share_ui":"jfk","server_time_ms":1378944177685,"gaia_session_id":"","enable_iframed_embed_api":true,"cup":"/folder/d/{folderId}/edit","docs-fut":"//docs.google.com/#folders/{folderId}","esid":true,"esubid":false,"docs-etbs":true,"enable_kennedy":true,"onePickImportDocumentUrl":"","opbu":"https://docs.google.com/picker","opru":"https://docs.google.com/relay.html","opdu":false,"ophi":"texmex","opuci":"","docs-se":false,"docs-ebcrsct":false,"docs-iror":false,"xdbcmUri":"https://docs.google.com/file/xdbcm.html","xdbcfAllowXpc":true,"docs-corsbc":false,"xdbcfAllowHostNamePrefix":true,"docs-spdy":false,"enable_client_docos":true,"enable_anchored_docos":true,"enable_docos_tickle":true,"gv_int_native":true,"tpc":true,"enable_pinned_revisions":false,"enable_edit_blob_revisions":false,"upload_url":"https://docs.google.com/upload/resumableupload","enable_toolbar":true,"enable_feedback_button":false,"enable_microscope":true,"enable_manage_timed_text":true,"video_embed_type":"PREFER_FLASH","enable_maps_embed":true,"maps_api_uri":"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBCjpnguVjzi6vS67NdBtyYuvCYz3yBxCY&sensor=false","maps_display_uri":"https://maps.google.com/maps","docs_abuse_link":"https://docs.google.com/abuse?id=0B9MOgXFCss2iSWpicmVKSW9OOWM","enable_csi":true,"csi_service_name":"texmex","third_party_default_icon_urls":{"icon16":"//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/generic_app_icon_16.png","icon32":"//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/generic_app_icon_32.png","icon64":"//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/generic_app_icon_64.png","icon128":"//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/generic_app_icon_128.png"},"enable_chrome_webstore_link":true};(function(){(function(){function d(a){this.t={};this.tick=function(a,c,b){b=void 0!=b?b:(new Date).getTime();this.t[a]=[b,c]};this.tick("start",null,a)}var a=new d;window.jstiming={Timer:d,load:a};if(window.performance&&window.performance.timing){var a=window.performance.timing,c=window.jstiming.load,b=a.navigationStart,a=a.responseStart;0=b&&(c.tick("*wtsrt",void 0,b),c.tick("wtsrt*","*wtsrt",a),c.tick("tbsd*","wtsrt_"))}try{a=null,window.chrome&&window.chrome.csi&&(a=Math.floor(window.chrome.csi().pageT),
c&&0tbnd",void 0,window.chrome.csi().startE),c.tick("tbnd","_tbnd",b))),null==a&&window.gtbExternal&&(a=window.gtbExternal.pageT()),null==a&&window.external&&(a=window.external.pageT,c&&0tbnd",void 0,window.external.startE),c.tick("tbnd","_tbnd",b))),a&&(window.jstiming.pt=a)}catch(e){}})();})();

JavaScript isn't enabled in your browser, so this file can't be opened. Enable and reload.
Search Images Maps Play YouTube News Gmail Drive More »Report abuse | Settings | Sign in temp1.txt  Comments ShareYou are using an unsupported browser. Some features may not work correctly. Upgrade to a modern browser, such as Google Chrome.Dismiss
FileEditViewHelp
DOCS_initializeModules({"core":[],"app":["core"]},{"core":["/static/file/client/js/123932484-edit_core__en_gb.js"],"app":["/static/file/client/js/1118393582-edit_app__en_gb.js"]}, 'core');_main('/file/d/0B9MOgXFCss2iSWpicmVKSW9OOWM', {'sid': '6249ba6d18211909','id': '0B9MOgXFCss2iSWpicmVKSW9OOWM', 'email': '', 'title': 'temp1.txt', 'description': '', 'mimetype': 'text/plain', 'fileExtension': 'txt', 'mediaType': 'text', 'revisions': [{"tags":[],"creatorDisplayName":"Kawsar Jahan","pinned":true,"filename":"temp1.txt","downloadUrl":"https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B9MOgXFCss2iSWpicmVKSW9OOWM&export=download&revid=0B9MOgXFCss2iaWN0a2p2b2x4dW4zcDBVL2lhTGhTajBaS3RnPQ","sizeInBytes":161,"docId":"0B9MOgXFCss2iaWN0a2p2b2x4dW4zcDBVL2lhTGhTajBaS3RnPQ","creationDateString":"10 Sep","creator":{"isMe":false,"nickname":"Kawsar Jahan","iconUrl":"images/doclist/contact_nopicture.png","editProfileUrl":"editProfile"}}],'obfuscatedUserId': 'ANONYMOUS_17612595759507348808','userDomain': '', 'embedPreviewUri': 'https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9MOgXFCss2iSWpicmVKSW9OOWM/preview','syncUpdates': [],'contentRenderer': 'gviewembed'},{"description":{"raw":"","formatted":""},"download":{"isMissingBlobRef":false,"filename":"temp1.txt","url":"https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B9MOgXFCss2iSWpicmVKSW9OOWM&export=download"},"revision":{"swfUrl":"/static/doclist/client/css/1531528182-uploaderapi.swf","busyIconImageUrl":"https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/loading_small.gif"},"sharing":{"is_private":false,"visibility_is_restricted_to_domain":false,"visibility_domain_display_name":""},"basicdetails":{"mimeType":"text/plain","lastModifiedDateString":"10 Sep","creationDateString":"10 Sep","fileSize":"161"},"thumbnail":{"thumbnail_128":"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/2lZYaNUzET3ObPtUlsycnF6LhTh_q0Q8GAyE8_F9Ic4IE_9o00anRyEAmglCuSwp_Jo2=s128","thumbnail_full":"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/2lZYaNUzET3ObPtUlsycnF6LhTh_q0Q8GAyE8_F9Ic4IE_9o00anRyEAmglCuSwp_Jo2=s1600"},"gviewembed":{"url":"https://docs.google.com/viewer?srcid=0B9MOgXFCss2iSWpicmVKSW9OOWM&pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v","embeduri":"https://docs.google.com/viewer?srcid=0B9MOgXFCss2iSWpicmVKSW9OOWM&pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true","nonredirectedgviewurl":"https://docs.google.com/viewer?srcid=0B9MOgXFCss2iSWpicmVKSW9OOWM&pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=true&redirect=false","isNativeGView":false},"webstoreui":{"mimeType":"text/plain","fileExtension":"txt","moreDriveAppsUrl":"https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/collection/drive_apps"}});

Comment: And what *is* happening? Output? Empty files? Exceptions?

Comment: What happens when you execute it? Bad URL, IO error, no content?

Comment: my output is showing some HTML value. I am giving my output here: e&a=v&chrome=true&redirect=false","isNativeGView":false},"webstoreui":{"mimeType":"text\/plain","fileExtension":"txt","moreDriveAppsUrl":"https:\/\/chrome.google.com\/webstore\/category\/collection\/drive_apps"}});</script></body></html>

Comment: I'm guessing what you have posted isn't the full output.  You should include it as part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The approach that you're taking of just making an http request to the google doc will probably result in you being re-directed to a login page or something else.  Provided that you were able to get to the document, you would then have to come up with a parsing strategy of their HTML structure, which is subject to change and really will not care about notifying you beforehand.

I would suggest instead that you look at the google developers website and look into the different apis that they have available.  It appears that they have REST apis that would be useful and it looks like they might have a pure java client as well.  I would check out this link: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java

Comment: thanks dsingleton. i have added my full output now. I have tried with HTML parsing in jsoup. but that code also did not give me the file content.

Comment: I have checked the link but could not understand what to do to read the content of the file. actually I have to program a such a code which will show(when I will run it from any computer connected to the network) the content of remote file.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't worked with the APIs, so I can't give a whole lot more guidance, but I can tell you for sure that just grabbing the html content and then parsing it will probably turn into an unmitigated nightmare.  I would recommend pushing through the documentation linked and trying to find some guides online or something instead of the current approach that you're taking.  You'll be much better off in the long run.